# Upgrading MongoDB from 4.2.9 to 4.4.0: Location13111: field not found, expected type date

Tags: mongodb

I'm running a sharded MongoDB instance and as per the instructions, the config servers are a replica set. I'm unable to upgrade from v4.2.9 to 4.4.0. Per the [upgrade instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/), I need to upgrade the config servers first, starting with a secondary. It already failed there. I shut down the secondary's instance, replaced the binaries, and restarted it. But it didn't start up again. The logs say the following (I removed the timestamps for clarity):

```
"msg":"The size storer reports that the oplog contains","attr":{"numRecords":53890848,"dataSize":13618131721}}
"msg":"Sampling the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation"}
"msg":"Sampling from the oplog to determine where to place markers for truncation","attr":{"from":{"$timestamp":{"t":1494750837,"i":1}},"to":{"$timestamp":{"t":1598687615,"i":1}}}}
"msg":"Taking samples and assuming each oplog section contains","attr":{"numSamples":253,"containsNumRecords":2124552,"containsNumBytes":536870917}}
"msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"Location13111: field not found, expected type date","file":"src/mongo/bson/bsonelement.h","line":810}}
"msg":"WiredTiger record store oplog processing finished","attr":{"durationMillis":21}}
"msg":"~WiredTigerRecordStore for: {ns}","attr":{"ns":"local.oplog.rs"}}
"msg":"Invariant failure","attr":{"expr":"_oplogManagerCount > 0","file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":2467}}
"msg":"\n\n***aborting after invariant() failure\n\n"}
"msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Aborted).\n"}}
"msg":"BACKTRACE: {bt}","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"55C91A79E621","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"2CBB621","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.606","s+":"1E1"},{"a":"55C91A79FCC9","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"2CBCCC9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"},{"a":"55C91A79D4B6","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"2CBA4B6","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9siginfo_tPv","s+":"66"},{"a":"7FAF200070E0","b":"7FAF1FFF6000","o":"110E0","s":"funlockfile","s+":"50"},{"a":"7FAF1FC89FFF","b":"7FAF1FC57000","o":"32FFF","s":"gsignal","s+":"CF"},{"a":"7FAF1FC8B42A","b":"7FAF1FC57000","o":"3442A","s":"abort","s+":"16A"},{"a":"55C9189E6C5F","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"F03C5F","s":"_ZN5mongo15invariantFailedEPKcS1_j","s+":"12C"},{"a":"55C9186CE4B6","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"BEB4B6","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine16haltOplogManagerEv.cold.1904","s+":"18"},{"a":"55C918B0711C","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"102411C","s":"_ZN5mongo21WiredTigerRecordStoreD1Ev","s+":"2FC"},{"a":"55C918B0D68B","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"102A68B","s":"_ZN5mongo29StandardWiredTigerRecordStoreD0Ev","s+":"1B"},{"a":"55C9186CEC5B","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"BEBC5B","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine21getGroupedRecordStoreEPNS_16OperationContextENS_10StringDataES3_RKNS_17CollectionOptionsENS_8KVPrefixE.cold.1921","s+":"57"},{"a":"55C919378A76","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"1895A76","s":"_ZN5mongo17StorageEngineImpl15_initCollectionEPNS_16OperationContextENS_8RecordIdERKNS_15NamespaceStringEb","s+":"316"},{"a":"55C91937A7BD","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"18977BD","s":"_ZN5mongo17StorageEngineImpl11loadCatalogEPNS_16OperationContextE","s+":"90D"},{"a":"55C91937E3D0","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"189B3D0","s":"_ZN5mongo17StorageEngineImplC1EPNS_8KVEngineENS_20StorageEngineOptionsE","s+":"270"},{"a":"55C918AC8005","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"FE5005","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"1A5"},{"a":"55C9193889EE","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"18A59EE","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"4CE"},{"a":"55C918A84587","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"FA1587","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi.isra.1409","s+":"3F7"},{"a":"55C918A88610","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"FA5610","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"650"},{"a":"55C9189F7849","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"F14849","s":"main","s+":"9"},{"a":"7FAF1FC772E1","b":"7FAF1FC57000","o":"202E1","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"F1"},{"a":"55C918A83A3A","b":"55C917AE3000","o":"FA0A3A","s":"_start","s+":"2A"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"4.9.0-7-amd64","version":"#1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13)","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"55C917AE3000","elfType":3,"buildId":"D7866CAA7FFAC402345915854064CD98A5B60C27"},{"b":"7FAF1FFF6000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0","elfType":3,"buildId":"16D609487BCC4ACBAC29A4EAA2DDA0D2F56211EC"},{"b":"7FAF1FC57000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"775143E680FF0CD4CD51CCE1CE8CA216E635A1D6"}]}}}}
```

It appears to boil down to the following error message:

> Location13111: field not found, expected type date.
> src/mongo/bson/bsonelement.h:810

Googling didn't turn up anything useful. I didn't proceed after that but had to revert to v4.2.9. (I wanted to keep the damage to the config secondary and not get the same issue with the shards.)

I'm on Debian 9.13 and I tried both `apt` to install MongoDB 4.4.0 and directly installing the Debian 9.2 binaries. The error was the same both times.

Any ideas what to do about this one?

Comment: You can try performing initial sync on each node instead of maintaining the data directory.

Comment: Yes, that would bypass the issue with the config servers. But I'm afraid the same thing is going to happen with the shards. At the moment, that seems too big of a risk to me. So I'd really like to know why the upgrade procedure doesn't work as outlined in the manuals.

Comment: I suggest running  --repair on your data directory, trying the upgrade again and if it fails submitting this issue via official support channels.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried --repair but only after the upgrade failed. Unfortunately, it didn't help. But next time, I'll try it before attempting the upgrade.